# swift using objective c class - use of undeclared type error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, symbol-not-found

right now I am developing a project using swift and I use some of class in objective c. I have set up bridge and most of them work fine. But I have a problem to override the method defined in objective class.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ASFTableViewPublicGlobals.h"

@class ASFTableView;

@protocol ASFTableViewDelegate <NSObject>

@optional

- (void)ASFTableView:(ASFTableView *)tableView DidScroll:(UIScrollView     *)aScrollView;

@end



@interface ASFTableView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<ASFTableViewDelegate> delegate;

- (void)ASFTableView:(ASFTableView *)tableView DidSelectRow:(NSDictionary *)rowDict WithRowIndex:(NSUInteger)rowIndex;

@end
```

As you see, the class in objective c is defined ASFTableView, and after I set up the bridge and everything, I define a class in swift

```
import UIkit

class asftable: ASFTableView {

}
```

This work without any error, but when I want to override the method

```
import UIkit

class asftable: ASFTableView {

override func ASFTableView(tableView: ASFTableView!, didSelectRow rowDict: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, withRowIndex rowIndex: UInt) {

} 

}
```

xcode will show up a use of undeclared type ASFTableView, I have try cmd+click on ASFTableView, it shows symbol not found. without override this method, I could jump to the code of ASFTableView.

Anyone see the solution of this situation?

Comment: class asftable: AsfT {
is this a typo error? or it's same in your code?

Comment: I'm just out here. Have worked too much times with swif and objective C but didn't saw such issue.

Comment: quit xcode and clean re run if it works. If still no success. Delete you bridging header and add it again

Comment: try this some time but does not work.. Stuck here for 2 days, sad

Comment: How did you set up objC bridging, what were your general steps?

Comment: just create a objective c file and #import "ASFTableView.h" , also set up in build setting to locate the bridging file

Comment: Try adding the class type at the end like this:  `override func ASFTableView( 'your var here') ->  ASFTableView! {}`